# AWX - How/Where to modify the Global Job settings

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

Environment:

- AWX - `16.0` within Docker on CentOS8
- Ansible `2.9.15`

Question:

Within the UI of `AWX Settings -> Job Settings`.
How do I modify the section "paths to expose to isolated jobs"

The `Edit` button does not currently work on this version so there has to be a config file somewhere that controls these options.
I need to add the option `AWX_PROOT_SHOW_PATHS: /var/lib/awx/.ssh` for jobs SSH connectivity.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the cli tool `awx-cli` to change AWX/Tower settings.
Install the tool on your machine which is running the containers (I use CentOS):

```
yum install ansible-tower-cli
```

Log in with your admin credentials:

```
awx-cli login admin
```

To list all available settings use the `setting list` parameter. You can use grep or less or whatever to filter output:

```
awx-cli setting list | grep AWX_PROOT_SHOW_PATHS
```

To change a value of a setting use the `setting modify` parameter. In your case it would look like this:

```
awx-cli setting modify AWX_PROOT_SHOW_PATHS '/your/path'
```

In AWX Version 16.0.0 a lot of settings in the Web-UI are not accesible so have to change them via awx-cli.

Comment: In the latest versions, you may need to install the awx-cli command with
`pip3 install awxkit`

The command is called `awx` and not `awx-cli`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Ansible package to modify the settings within the AWX platform as of version 16.0
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/awx/awx/tower_settings_module.html